# How to re-open the Java Console in Firefox 3 after I've closed it

Tags: java, firefox, applet

I'm using firefox3 to run a Java Applet (on Linux). normally, when the JVM launches the Java Console window opens so I can see output from the Applet (stack traces etc.).

However, if I *close* the console there appears to be no way of getting it back short of restarting Firefox (I have to close the console because it makes startup of the applet hang for some reason, which is another problem).

There was a Firefox extension called "Open Java Console" that solved this problem, but it hasn't been ported to Firefox3.

Is there a way to re-open the Java console in Firefox3 ?

Note that I'm using Firefox3 on *Linux* (Ubuntu 8.04), where the "Tools->Java Console" menu option does not appear for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the Web developer add-on, so pressing Ctrl-Shift-O opens the Java console. (Firefox 3 on Ubuntu)

Comment: This works a treat except for crashing Firefox if the JVM hasn't loaded yet (which I can live with).

Answer (score 0):

I also have the Web Developer add-on, but I couldn't get it to open the Java Console, so now I right click the Java icon in the task bar and click "Open Console" and that does it for me.